# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ',' or ')' on line 5

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

```
<?php

function ju_enqueue()
{
            register_style(handle:'ju_google_fonts', src:'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,400italic,600,700|Raleway:300,400,500,600,700|Crete+Round:400italic');
            wp_register_style(handle:'ju_bootstrap', src:get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/css/bootstrap.css');
            wp_register_style(handle:'ju_style', src:get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/css/style.css');
            wp_register_style(handle:'ju_dark', src:get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/css/dark.css');
            wp_register_style(handle:'ju_font_icons', src:get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/css/font-icons.css');
            wp_register_style(handle:'ju_animate', src:get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/css/animate.css');
            wp_register_style(handle:'ju_magnific_popup', src:get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/css/magnific-popup.css');
            wp_register_style(handle:'ju_responsive', src:get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/css/responsive.css');
            wp_register_style(handle:'ju_custom', src:get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/css/custom.css');

            wp_enqueue_style(handle:'ju_google_fonts');
            wp_enqueue_style(handle:'ju_bootstrap');
            wp_enqueue_style(handle:'ju_style');
            wp_enqueue_style(handle:'ju_dark');
            wp_enqueue_style(handle:'ju_font_icons');
            wp_enqueue_style(handle:'ju_animate');
            wp_enqueue_style(handle:'ju_magnific_popup');
            wp_enqueue_style(handle:'ju_responsive');
            wp_enqueue_style(handle:'ju_custom');
}
```

WHAT iz wrong with that code......i'm getting this error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ',' or ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\udemy\includes\front\enqueue.php on line 5

Comment: does my answer help you solving your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try without `handle:` and `src:` in your function call

```
function ju_enqueue()
{
  register_style('ju_google_fonts', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,400italic,600,700|Raleway:300,400,500,600,700|Crete+Round:400italic');
  wp_register_style('ju_bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/css/bootstrap.css');
  wp_register_style('ju_style', get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/css/style.css');
  wp_register_style('ju_dark', get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/css/dark.css');
  wp_register_style('ju_font_icons', get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/css/font-icons.css');
  wp_register_style('ju_animate', get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/css/animate.css');
  wp_register_style('ju_magnific_popup', get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/css/magnific-popup.css');
  wp_register_style('ju_responsive', get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/css/responsive.css');
  wp_register_style('ju_custom', get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/css/custom.css');

  wp_enqueue_style('ju_google_fonts');
  wp_enqueue_style('ju_bootstrap');
  wp_enqueue_style('ju_style');
  wp_enqueue_style('ju_dark');
  wp_enqueue_style('ju_font_icons');
  wp_enqueue_style('ju_animate');
  wp_enqueue_style('ju_magnific_popup');
  wp_enqueue_style('ju_responsive');
  wp_enqueue_style('ju_custom');
}
```

You should also look into this https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style